# What type of internet cable/modem? China Telecom, home internet, Shanghai

Tags: internet-connection, modem

I live in Shanghai and I'd like to replace the less than great modem/wireless router that the local ISP (China Telecom) gave us when we moved in.

The problem is that the internet cable that goes into the flat has a type of connector that I've never seen before. I've asked around with my friends but they have seen this particular type of connector either. I've also tried China Telecom customer service, but have not been able to get any clear information from them about this particular question.

[image]

Comment: post a pic to imgur, flikr etc & someone with the necessary rep can inline it

Comment: Ah great, please find here - http://imgur.com/S5tjZB9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks a bit like an SC fibre-optic connector

[image][image]

---

See [Setting up Internet access with China Telecom](http://unsolicitedbutoffered.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/setting-up-access-point-with-china.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that definitely looks right. Just a quick question, do you have any idea about what modem I might want to look into buying to replace the the one that came from the ISP? If I type 'sc fibre optic modem' into Google I get a lot of hits for what looks like pretty heavy duty industrial kit...

Comment: @Daniel. I can't really help with search terms. Assuming your Mandarin is OK, I'd take the photo and the old device to a nearby shop. Unless you are confident about configuring authentication, it might be best to use a China Telecom provided fibre-optic modem with a separate wireless router of your own choice. In the Internets, "cable broadband routers" would find things that connect to modems by Ethernet UTP 8P8C (RJ45) connections.

Comment: no worries at all and thanks a lot for your help. Good idea to ask China Telecom if I could just get a modem from them, I'll give that a go :)